# Drupal 7 database query: how to write a condition that a field's first letter cannot be a, b, c, ...z?

Tags: database, drupal

I would like to use Drupal 7's database API to write a query that retrieve all records whose titles do not start with a, b, c, or z.

I got stuck in writing the condition part: $query->condition(?)

Thanks for any help!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution and it works, but it does not look elegant.

```
$query -> where('SUBSTRING(n.title, 1, 1) not in (:letter)', 
          array(':letter' => array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
                                   'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                                   'u','v','w','x','y','z')));
```